# What is considered "Too much data" in react state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm currently building an app with a dashboard that lists a ton of statistics. The data is loaded via an API and stored in my component's state (currently not using redux — just plain react). I'm loading more than 100.000 (small) rows of data, and storing them as an array in state. My question is: at what point does the size of my state become a problem? Surely there will be memory limitations at some point? is 100.000 entries in an array a problem, is 1.000.000? And if yes, what are alternative solutions to handling this amount of data? Is this where redux can help?

Comment: Did you finally get a workaround? I'm experiencing an issue with lag on my input's onChange method on components where I have a moderate (in my opinion) amount of data stored in state. Were you able to store loads of data without lag? How did you do it?

Comment: @EricMcWinNEr I concluded that storing lots of data and aggregating it in React is generally a bad idea — at least for my use case. I ended up using the the aggregate framework in MongoDB serverside, and do all the calculations that way. React only received the final calculations, instead of all the data. Instantly solved my problems, and made react super fast. And honestly the Mongo aggregation framework is way faster than what I did in React anyway. May not be useful for you, but that's how I got around it.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I'm not using MongoDB in my use case but I get the point. Thing is I'm aggregating data, paginating it and sending react what I feel in my opinion is a moderate chunk of data, but the lag is visible, so much so I had to make my input elements for that particular component use Refs instead of state and even then, onSubmit actions have a visible lag.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the most part, it does not matter *Where* you store this data as much as how much of data you are storing. All of the data that you store, regardless of whether in a store or in a static variable, is stored in RAM. Because of this, your application might crash the browser because of taking too much resources.

A much better solution for storage (If you absolutely have to store data client-side) is to use something called [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API). IndexedDB stores data in your hard disk instead of RAM

In most use-cases however, it is recommended to store the data in the backend, paginate it, and then send only the individual pages to the client as needed. This ensures that

- The client doesn't have to load a massive chunk of data before the application works.
- The client does not have to store large amounts of data in RAM.